# How to avoid automatic ASCII encoding on Python 3?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, character-encoding, ascii

I'm working on an encryption program in Python 3 right now, but I am having some problems with ASCII encoding. For example, if I want to write a text file from python that rights Ϩ (which is `chr(1000)`) into a text file, and I do:

```
a_file = open('chr_ord.txt', 'w')
a_file.write(chr(1000))
a_file.close()
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ...
  File "C:/Comp_Sci/Coding/printRAW.py", line 3, in <module>
    a_file.write(chr(1000))
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03e8' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

And if I try:

```
a_file = open('chr_ord.txt', 'w')
a_file.write(ascii(chr(1000)))
a_file.close()
```

Python doesn't crash, but the text file contains `'\u03e8'` instead of the desired Ϩ

Is there any way I can go around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python 3 way is to use the `encoding` parameter when opening the file. Eg. encode the file as UTF-8

```
a_file = open('chr_ord.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

The default is your system ANSI code page, which doesn't contain the `Ϩ` character.